# Update query in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, sql-update

I have one requirement in `Yii` where I have to update one table based on some condition. And I have to update the column with `new_val =  previous_value + new_val`. But the code is not working as expected.

The code I tried is

```
$update = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->update('tbl_post', array('star'=>('star' + 1),'total'=>('total' + $ratingAjax)),
'id=:id',array(':id'=>$post_id));
```

In normal query the query will be

```
UPDATE tbl_post set star= star + 1,total = total + '$ratingAjax' where id = 1
```

Anybody knows where is mistake?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$update = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->update('tbl_post', 
        array(
            'star'=>new CDbExpression('star + 1'),
            'total'=>new CDbExpression('total + :ratingAjax', array(':ratingAjax'=>$ratingAjax))
        ),
        'id=:id',
        array(':id'=>$post_id)
    );
```

Using `CDbExpression` will allow you to send an expression for what to update the column value to be.

See: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#update-detail

and: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbExpression#__construct-detail

Answer (score 3):

Your working with strings, try this :

```
$update = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->update('tbl_post', array('star'=>'star + 1','total'=> 'total + '.$ratingAjax),
'id=:id',array(':id'=>$post_id));
```

Comment: `star and total` is integer field not string.

Comment: The SQL Query you are building is a string not an integer, this should generate the string `UPDATE tbl_post set star= star + 1,total = total + [$ratingAjax variable value] where id = 1`

Comment: 'star' + 1 this is not concatenation, this is string + integer, it will return 1 so your sql will be `... set star = 1 ...`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
   Post::model()->updateCounters(
        array('star'=>1),
        array('total'=>$ratingAjax),
        array('condition' => "id = :id"),
        array(':id' => $post_id),
    );
```

It will increment, not set the values