# execute update query with if condition in yii

Tags: yii

I have a update query i.e.

update subscribers set credits_balance=IF((subid=3 or subid=6), 0, credits) where agentid={$agentid} and NOT subid IN (7, 8, 9) order by uid desc limit 1

how i execute this in yii.

Comment: check this link...it may help you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641947/update-query-in-yii

Comment: Thank you bt is it possible to use sql if condition in yii

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to use if condition in yii query...hope this will help you

```
$update = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->update('subscribers', 
        array(
            'credits_balance'=>new CDbExpression('IF((subid=3 or subid=6), 0, credits)'),

        ),
        'agentid=:id',
        array(':id'=>$agentid)
    );
```